# Ruby error: no such file to load -- haml (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am getting this error when I run my project:

```
C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': 
no such file to load -- haml (MissingSourceFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) rubygem?

```
gem install haml
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add:

```
config.gem haml
```

to your environment.rb file